# Stack overflow error or exception?

Tags: c++, recursion

Why does the following ends up with no error?

```
void func()
{
   func();
}

int main()
{
   func();
}
```

Comment: Does the application just hang, or does it end with back at the command prompt with no remark?  The correctness of the answers you gotten likely depends on you answer to this question.

Comment: The output says: `Press any key to continue . . .`

Comment: So it is some kind of crash, rather than a continuous loop consuming CPU?

Comment: What happens when you do press a key?

Comment: @vbence It exits and closes the console window.

Comment: This suggests that it is definitely not an infinite loop. That way the program would never exit. You have to disassemble the resulting code. I can not recommend you a program for that without knowing the OS and architecture you are compiling to.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops/2181045#2181045

Comment: @Ant: Which OS, which C++ compiler?

Comment: "This suggests it is not an infinite loop". Agreed. I think most of the answers here suggesting that is a compiler optimization into an infinite loop, in spite of their upvotes, are wrong.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

*In theory*, it would overflow the stack (because, even if no local variables are used, each call would add the previous return address on the stack); *in practice*, with optimizations enabled, it doesn't overflow because of [tail call optimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call), which actually avoids any resource consumption transforming the call in a jump, thus not consuming the stack.

This can be easily seen by [examining the optimized assembly](https://godbolt.org/g/N4Zmc9) generated by the OP code:

```
func():
.L2:
        jmp     .L2
main:
.L4:
        jmp     .L4
```

`func` is optimized to an infinite loop, both the "freestanding version" and the inlined call in `main`.

Notice that this is coherent with the C++ standard for the "as if" rule: the compiled program must run *as if* it were what you requested in the code (in terms of effect), and since the stack size is just an implementation limit, the generated code that uses a `call` and the one that uses a `jmp` are equivalent.

***But***: this is an even more particular case, as the standard even says that infinite looping (defined as ["not terminating and not having some side-effect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41320725/is-infinite-loop-still-undefined-behavior-in-c-if-it-calls-shared-library)) is actually undefined behavior, so in theory the compiler would be allowed to omit that call entirely.

Comment: +1 to this answer, the more explicit version of what I meant to say.

Answer (score 8):

Likely, your compiler optimized it away and turned it into a `while(true){}` construct.

Comment: @GMan: It's all in the wording, I guess.

Comment: @David: Yup, sometimes I just miss the mark and make too many assumptions, oh well.

Answer (score 5):

It *does* end with a *Segmentation fault* on my Linux system - Valgrind indicates a possible stack overflow, which is of course true, since for each function call a new stack frame is required.

*However*, enabling optimisations in the compiler reduces this whole program to an infinite loop, which, naturally, does not end at all:

```
        .file   "so.c"
        .text
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl func
        .type   func, @function
func:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L2:
        jmp     .L2
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   func, .-func
        .p2align 4,,15
.globl main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB1:
        .cfi_startproc
        .p2align 4,,10
        .p2align 3
.L5:
        jmp     .L5
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE1:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.4.3"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

Here's the interesting part:

```
.L5:
        jmp     .L5
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are compiling and running this on Windows in a command window, you may get a crash but without any remarks from the OS.  (We build a funny compiler and run into this problem a lot).  Microsoft's claim is that when program does very bad things, they can't recover... so they simply kill the process and restart the command prompt.  LIkely in your case, after you've recursed to the stack limit, when the trap handler attempts to do something (like push trap status on the stack) there isn't any space and Windows kills your process.

I personally think this is inexcusable behavior.  If my process does something bad, the OS should *always* complain.  It might say, "process terminated with prejudice", along with some kind of indication ("you ran out of stack in the last-ditch error handler") but it should say something.

[Multics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/501208/what-projects-do-you-feel-sorry-for/1183967#1183967) got this right in 1966. Its a shame we haven't applied these lessons in over 40 years.

Answer (score 1):

On my machine it ends with a segfault (like infinite recursion should).

Maybe your shell isn't reporting the segfault. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Back in the olden days, when you wanted to over-optimize an ASM program there was a practice: may times a function ended with calling an other function (then returning). It would look something like:

```
somefunc:

    ; do some things

    CALL someotherfunc
    RET

someotherfunc:

    ; do some other things

    RET
```

This way when `CALL someotherfunc` happened the address of the next instruction (the `RET`) is saved into the stack and then `someotherfunc` returned just to execute the a return. Exactly the same results can be achieved with a `JMP` to `someotherfunc`. This way the stack will not contain the address of the last instruction, but it will contain the original caller's address. So when `someotherfunc` makes it's `RET` the program will continue at the original caller.

So the optimized code would look like:

```
somefunc:

    ; do some things

    JMP someotherfunc

someotherfunc:

    ; do some other things

    RET
```

And if `somefunc` is calling itself as the last instruction (in fact that is the only instruction), it would indeed look like:

```
somefunc:

    JMP somefunc
```