# constructor or copy constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, copy-constructor

In the book *Generic Programming and the STL* (Chinese edition), it says:

> `X x = X()` will call the copy constructor.

It seems a little weird to me. And I write a test program like this

```
#include <iostream>

class Test {

public:

    Test() {
        std::cout << "This is ctor\n";
    }

    Test(const Test&) {
        std::cout << "This is copy-ctor\n";
    }

};

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    Test t = Test();
    return 0;
}
```

The output is "This is ctor". ok, now I'm confused, which is right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nomimally yes, a temporary is default-constructed, and then the copy constructor is invoked to copy it into your object `t`.

However, in practice the copy can be optimised out — *even though it has side effects* (the console output):

> `[n3290: 8.5/16]`: [..] In certain cases, an implementation is
>   permitted to eliminate the copying inherent in this
>   direct-initialization by constructing the intermediate result directly
>   into the object being initialized; see 12.2, 12.8.

And (in conjunction with the example given in the same clause):

> `[n3290: 12.2/2]`: [..] An implementation might use a temporary in
>   which to construct X(2) before passing it to f() using `X`’s copy
>   constructor; alternatively, `X(2)` might be constructed in the space
>   used to hold the argument. [..]

But the copy constructor *does* still have to exist, even though it might not be invoked.

Anyway, if you compile with optimisations turned off (or, with GCC, possibly `-fno-elide-constructors`), you will see:

```
This is ctor
This is copy-ctor
```

Comment: In gcc, you may have to use `-fno-elide-constructors`, since even `-O0` doesn't prevent elision, I think.

Comment: The copy can be elided even when it is not *trivial*, the copy is elided by constructing the temporary in place of the local variable. The complexity of the object or the copy is irrelevant to that optimization.

Comment: @Tomalak: Credits (and +50) to Steve Jessop for [discovering that option](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6364365/can-different-optimization-levels-lead-to-functionally-different-code) :-)

Comment: Now wait. Weren't you the one who was so pissed-off the other day about those who start out their answer with just two sentences and then expand on that incrementally? `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Ah, but my answer was correct even in its most minimal form. IIRC the other day I was irritated by an answer that started off life as, basically, "answer coming soon..."

Comment: @sbi: More likely we are referring to distinct instances. :)

Comment: @Tomalak: Well, I am referring to the one I was referrin when I asked this question. `:)`

Comment: @sbi: Evidently I'm remembering a different one!

Answer (score 4):

In theory, `X x = X()` will call the default constructor to create a temporary object, and copy that into `x` using the copy constructor.

In practice, compilers are allowed to skip the copy construction part and default-construct `x` directly (which, as David points out in his comment, still requires the copy constructor to be syntactically accessible, though). Most compilers do that at least when optimizations are enabled.

Comment: It is important to note that the copy constructor must be available, even if the copy is elided. That is, if it is not accessible the compiler will reject the line with an error.

Comment: @David: You're right. I've incorporated that into my answer. Thanks for bringing this up.

Answer (score 2):

This is a case where a form of [Return Value Optimisation(RVO)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (Also known as [Copy Elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision)) can help out a lot on optimisation.  The wikipedia page linked has a very good explanation of what is going on.

Comment: I don't think that's strictly correct. There's no function call here that returns an `X` (remember that constructors do not have return values). This is copy elision, which is a related, but distinct concept.

Comment: I agree. This is not strictly RVO (though it's related).

Comment: @Tomak: This is not entirely incorrect too. This is a variant of *that kind* of optimization. +1 to counterbalance the downvote.

Comment: @Prasoon: Counterbalancing is wrong. It is not your job to remove other people's right to vote.

Comment: And, even if RVO were an appropriate term, if nothing else this answer doesn't really explain what's going on with the OP's code. For that reason alone it's not a good response.

Comment: @Goz: Better, yes. What's going on here is copy elision; RVO is a _specific_ form of copy elision that is not strictly involved here.