# What happens when one places a semi-colon after a while loop's condition?

Tags: c#, loops, syntax, while-loop

I've come across a situation like this a few times:

```
while (true) {

while (age == 5); //What does this semi-colon indicate?
//Code
//Code
//Code

}
```

The `while(true)` indicates that this is an infinite loop, but I have trouble understanding what the semi-colon after the `while` condition accomplishes, isn't it equivalent to this?:

```
while (age == 5) { }

//Code
//Code
```

In other words, does it mean that the `while` loop is useless as it never enters the block?

Comment: Are you asking about C or C#? You tagged the question with both.

Comment: I havnt a clue... logically itll do nothing

Comment: I've seen it occur in both, does it behave differently in both languages?

Comment: If `age == 5` you will get an infinite loop. It will only exit if `age != 5` at some stage (different thread?).

Comment: "does it mean that the while loop is useless as it never enters the block?" Not if `age == 5`. In that case, it's an infinite loop. If `age == 5`, then `age == 5` is `true`, so it means `while (true) { }`. If `age != 5`, then `age == 5` is `false`, so it means `while (false) { }`.

Comment: The JIT compiler will translate that to the HCF machine instruction (Halt and Catch Fire).  Putting out that fire is machine dependent.  Background info is here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halt_and_Catch_Fire

Comment: @Oded The syntax is the same in either language, but I think the `c` tag ought to be removed judging by the top answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
while (age == 5);     // empty statement
```

is equivalent to

```
while (age == 5) { }  // empty block
```

**Update:** Even if there is no body to execute, doesn't mean that the loop terminates. Instead it will simply loop repeatedly over the conditional (*which may have or rely upon side-effects*) until it is satisfied. Here is the equivalent form with a `goto`:

```
loop:
if (age == 5)
  goto loop;
```

This construct is *sometimes* used as a [busy-loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) waiting on a flag to be changed in threaded code. (The exact use and validity varies a good bit by language, algorithm, and execution environment.)

I find the use of `;` for an <del>"empty block"</del> empty statement a *questionable construct to use* because of issues like this:

```
while (age == 5); {
   Console.WriteLine("I hate debugging");
}
```

(I have seen this bug several times before, when new code was added.)

Happy coding.

Comment: That's what I thought - what's confusing me is that I've seen it done countless times to illustrate multithreading synchronisation issues. I doubt it's a mistake since it's repeated.

Comment: @Sean It's equivalent syntax. Presumably `age` is ("volatile" and) set by another thread -- so it's not necessarily a "mistake" to use this idiom (but I argue against the specific construct).

Comment: I read somewhere that the compiler is allowed to optimise away infinite loops such as this; let me see if I can find where I read this...

Comment: Ah, see these inconclusive questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3592557/optimizing-away-a-while1-in-c0x.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth It seems like it'd depend upon the scope of `age` (as for if the compile could really detect such code never had an effect). Nice reads, thanks.

Comment: ';' is not used as replacement for empty block, instead its an empty statement. "while(condition) statement" is also a way to write while loops with single statement.

Comment: @ChethanRavindranath Thank you. I have made some minor edits as such.

Answer (score 1):

`while (age == 5);` gets stuck into an infinite loop. In c `;` is a null terminator. The compiler assumes that the above loop has only one statement that is `;` which causes the loop to be iterated over infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

a statement consisting of only

`;`

is a null statement. It is the same as a block (also called compound statement) with nothing inside

```
{
}
```

They both perform no operations.

Answer (score 0):

If we put `;` anywhere it means `null` statement (statement that does nothing).

When we write

```
while(true);
```

It means a while loop an a statement that does nothing. It is similar to the

```
while(true)
i++;
```

Here statement is not `null` but in the previous case statement was `null`.