# Finding the biggest number of three using if-else. Why it doesn't want to compile?

Tags: c#, if-statement

I'm a beginner in programming, and i'm really wondering what's my mistake here :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int b = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    if ((a > b) && (a > c))
    {
       Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    else
    {
       if ((b > a) && (b > c)) ;
       {
          Console.WriteLine(b);
       }
       else
       {
          Console.WriteLine(c);
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: See [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706139/what-happens-when-one-places-a-semi-colon-after-a-while-loops-condition) for why your semicolon after the if statement is incorrect.

Comment: In the line `if ((b > a) && (b > c))` you don't need the `(b > a)`.  You already know `a` is not the largest, you only care about `b` and `c`.

Answer (score 13):

```
if ((b > a) && (b > c)) ;
```

Remove the `;`

Answer (score 1):

You can't use in your if condition `;`. Remove it.

```
if ((b > a) && (b > c))
{
      Console.WriteLine(b);
}
```

And you need one more `}` end of you code.

**Edit**: Actually you can use `;` with your if condition. For example;

```
if ((b > a) && (b > c));
```

is equal

```
if ((b > a) && (b > c))
{

}
```