# How to clear buffer in receiving multiple strings?

Tags: c

If I enter `str1` longer than length 10, the rest of it remains in the buffer and gets entered into my `str2`. How to clear the buffer before `str2`, so I can input it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str1[10];
    char str2[10]; 
    fgets(str1,10,stdin);
    fgets(str2,10,stdin);

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried it earlier,it wasn't working.

Comment: @jamesdlin sorry if i was wrong. Can you explain how so?

Comment: `fflush` is not defined for `stdin`.  See http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush.html and http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/stdinflush2.html

Answer (score 2):

After `fgets(str1,10,stdin);` do

```
while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

This would clear the input buffer after 'str1' is read.

So your code should be

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char str1[10];
    char str2[10]; 
    int c;
    str1[0]=0;
    str2[0]=0;
    fgets(str1,10,stdin);
    if( (str1[0]!=0) && (!strrchr(str1,'\n')) )
        while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
    fgets(str2,10,stdin);
    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What if there's a `'\n'` within the first 10 chars of input?

Comment: @JimBalter Thanks for pointing it out. Made the necessary edit.

Comment: Still, you don't test the return from `fgets`; you may access an uninitialized `str1` (e.g. for empty input).

Comment: @Jens Thanks for the heads up. Fixed it.

Comment: @NithinBhaskar is that ` ; ` after while loop intentional ? clear me if I am missing something silly here

Comment: @Bingo the ';' will cause the program to loop repeatedly in the while loop as long as the condition is satisfied. In this code, this will make sure that the characters remaining in the buffer after 'str1' is read will be flushed out of the buffer.

Comment: @NithinBhaskar ooppss I have been taking it other way for years :) thanks and have already upvoted you +1

Comment: @Bingo refer this link for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8706139/what-happens-when-one-places-a-semi-colon-after-a-while-loops-condition

Answer (score 0):

A different way: avoid fgets(), and read characters one by one. This allows you to handle all the conditions inside one loop:

```
int main(void)
{
    char str1[12];
    char str2[13];
    size_t pos;
    int ch;

    for (pos=0;;) {
      ch = getc(stdin);
      if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF ) break;
      if (pos < sizeof str1 -1) str1[pos++] = ch;
      }
    str1[pos] = 0;

    for (pos=0;;) {
      ch = getc(stdin);
      if (ch == '\n' || ch == EOF ) break;
      if (pos < sizeof str2 -1) str2[pos++] = ch;
      }
    str2[pos] = 0;

    printf( "str1='%s', str2=%s'\n", str1, str2);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LEN 9
#define READBUF_LEN 4092

int main(void)
{
    char str1[MAX_LEN+1];
    char str2[MAX_LEN+1]; 
    char readbuf[READBUF_LEN+1];

    fgets(readbuf,READBUF_LEN,stdin);
    strncpy(str1, readbuf,MAX_LEN);
    str1[MAX_LEN]='\0';

    fgets(readbuf,READBUF_LEN,stdin);
    strncpy(str2, readbuf,MAX_LEN);
    str2[MAX_LEN]='\0';

    puts(str1);
    puts(str2);
    return 0;
}
```

Yeah, I know, what if someone enters more than 4092 characters... There's a big chance of that happening.