# Echo Option from 1 single column

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

Hello guys I have this table :

```
ID| NUM_Slides |P1 | P2 | P3 | P4 | P5 | P6 | P7 | P8 | P9 | P10 | P11 | P12
3 | 2          |1  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0  | 0   | 0   | 0
```

I want to select the values only from P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,P11 and P12 and insert them into a `<option>` tag

I got this so far but dont work

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,P11,P12 FROM slider_settings_img where slider_settings_img.ID = $ID";
$result1 =$connect->query($query);
$resultado = $result1->fetch_all();
?>

<select name ="selectedValue" id="selected" >
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;?>
<option value=""<?php echo $row1[1];?>"><?php echo $row1[1];?>"</option>
<?php endwhile;?>
</select>
```

because my query only return 1 array I want the Options to be display 1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0

can some 1 help me

Comment: `<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;` <<< issue - end of statement. In turn; typo.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Did you mean that the extraneous `;` was causing the problem? I don't think that matters when using the alternate loop syntax.

Comment: @Don'tPanic Ummm... I'm pretty sure it does ;-) it ends that statement. Here http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.instruction-separation.php pretty sure you've seen that ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- only if you're using `{}`.

Comment: @Don'tPanic try out their code then, am pretty sure *the buck will stop there*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems.

1. `$resultado = $result1->fetch_all();` You can't fetch any more rows in your while loop if you've already fetched them all.
2. `while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)):;` Your query selects one row. You don't need to use a while loop at all.
3. That while loop is set up to iteratively fetch rows from a query result, but you need to fetch one row and iterate over its columns.
4. Couple of important typos.

---

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT P1,P2,P3,P4,P5,P6,P7,P8,P9,P10,P11,P12
          FROM slider_settings_img where slider_settings_img.ID = $ID";
$result1 = $connect->query($query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1);    // fetch one row
?>
<select name ="selectedValue" id="selected" >
<!-- iterate over each column of the row -->
<?php foreach ($row as $col): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $col ?>"><?php echo $col ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

Comment: `<?php foreach ($row as $col): ?>` => `<?php foreach ($row as $col):; ?>` as an FYI, will end *lol*

Comment: well that is quite odd

Comment: @Fred-ii- it's waiting for the endforeach. It sees the `;` as just another statement before that.

Comment: oh wait a minute; that may be true for a `foreach`, but not for a `while` loop

Comment: Just tried it @Fred-ii- Its ugly but the while works with the `;`

Comment: I mean, don't get me wrong. The `;` shouldn't be there. It just doesn't do anything in this case. It messes things up if it comes before a brace because it separates the loop definition from the body, but with the alternate syntax it's just another statement inside the loop.

Comment: @Don'tPanic It "work's but I need to have only 12 options with this code I have 24 the double you know why?

Comment: (`C#` (and php)) https://stackoverflow.com/q/8706139/1415724 --- http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: @RafaelSousa Ah, probably because no fetch style was specified in `mysqli_fetch_array`, and it's using `MYSQLI_BOTH` by default.

Comment: @RafaelSousa try using `mysqli_fetch_assoc` instead. I updated the answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That Q is using braces, though.

Comment: @Don'tPanic what braces? to me, braces are `{...}` did you mean parentheses `(...)`? I'm getting rather confused by everything *lol!*

Comment: @Fred-ii- lol sorry, I'm not doing a great job expressing what I think the reason is. One more attempt: https://3v4l.org/h1YRd

Comment: @Don'tPanic No worries. I'm just wondering about the OP here and what's the status of the question.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
<select name ="selectedValue" id="selected" >
<?php while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result1)) 
{
    for($i=2; $i<13; $i++) {
        echo '<option value="'.$row1[$i]'">'.$row1[1].'</option>';
    }
} 
?>
</select>
```