# Does C dialect affect optimization in gcc?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization, dialect

Does C dialect affect optimization in gcc?
That is (all optimization options being held the same) will gcc produce faster/slower/larger/smaller code for ANSI vs C99 vs ...?

Comment: I can think of at least one case off the top of my head where it could: [Are compilers allowed to eliminate infinite loops?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2178115/1708801)

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour But it doesn't mean GCC will actually eliminate them, even if allowed..

Comment: @EugeneSh. it does not, I did say *could*

Comment: @Shafik OK ... but I was looking for something more real-world-ish that might actually affect my code.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour: "... controlling expression is not a constant expression ...". `1` _is_, a _constant expression_. I really would wonder if a compiler would remove such a loop. It may, however, optimize-out any expressions inside the loop if thier side-effects are not used externally. That would be, normal optimizations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It could, likely.

One difference between C89 ("ANSI C") and C99 is the `restrict` keyword added with C99, which is specifically geared towards improving optimization. While your code may not explicitly use it (because you wrote C89 code), the C language headers like <string.h> may declare function prototypes using `restrict` when in C99 mode. This may or may not have an effect. You'll only know when you look at the generated code.