# What for (;;) and while(); mean in C

Tags: c, for-loop, while-loop

I am looking at some example codes and I saw someone did this

```
for (;;) {
// ...
}
```

Is that equivalent to `while(1) { }` ?

And what does `while(condition);` do? I don't get the reason behind putting `';'` instead of `{}`

Comment: The code is like `for(;;) { while(condition); }`.  So those 2 are just pretty much one `while(condition) { }` loop?

Comment: `while(condition);` makes more sense when you consider than "condition" could include increments, decrements, function calls, etc...

Comment: yes the loop is like this `while((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n'); `

Comment: If you have a question about cryptic code, it's best to quote the code literally.

Comment: @m69 ...or rather `for(;;) { condition; }`, which keeps going if `condition` is false.

Comment: @PTN In `while((buff[n++] = getchar()) != '\n');`, the condition itself does something, and its value will change as it goes becoming false eventually (it reads characters into a buffer until a newline is read, then the loop ends).

Comment: "*Is that equivalent to `while(1) { }`?*" -- Yes

Comment: Please clarify whether you are asking about an empty loop , or a loop that contains some statements

Answer (score 8):

yes,

```
for(;;){}
```

is an infinite loop

Comment: Note that this loop [causes undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops/) in C11.  (In C99 it was unclear whether or not it did).  `while(1) {}` does not cause undefined behaviour, so those two loop constructs are not the same.

Answer (score 8):

> And what does while(condition); do? I don't get the reason behind putting ';' instead of {}

Well, your question is what happens if you put or you do not put a semicolon after that while condition? The computer identifies the semicolon as an empty statement.

Try this:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a = 5, b = 10;

    if (a < b){
        printf("True");
    }


    while (a < b); /* infinite loop */
        printf("This print will never execute\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Right, the empty statement from the semicolon is the loop body.  But sometimes that's intentional if the work is done in the *condition*.

Comment: The print may execute because `while (a < b);` causes undefined behaviour. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops/) for further discussion

Answer (score 2):

`for(;;)` and `while(1)` are both infinite loops, and compile to the same opcodes:

```
L2:
    jmp     L2
```

Which means there is no speed difference, as the disassembly is exactly the same.

Comment: Did you mean `for(;;){}` and `while(1){}` ?   Assuming so, your assembly code is only one possible result, other systems may differ.

Answer (score 1):

while just loops though a single statement until the condition is false. It doesn't have to be a compound statement (this thing: {}), it can be any statement. ; is a statement that does nothing.

```
while(getchar() != '\n');
```

will loop until you hit enter, for example. Though, this is bad practice since it will hog the thread; adding a call to a sleep method in the loop is better.