# Why is for(;;); an infinite loop?

Tags: c++, c, for-loop

I've written infinite loops like this numerous times over the years in both C and C++, but today is the first time I really thought about it -- why is it an infinite loop when the condition clause is empty? One would expect you'd have to write something like `for(;true;);` to get a valid infinite loop?

`while();` doesn't compile nor does `while(;);`

Anyways, I like the `for(;;);` syntax and use it often, but is it a special case to treat an empty condition block as true or are there other cases in C or C++ where an empty condition expression is interpreted as true?

Comment: Because when a condition clause is empty it defaults to true, hence the loop. That's how C++ specifies `for` to behave. Mostly the same reason why water is wet.

Comment: `while();` is a compilation error so an empty condition clause does not always default to true.

Comment: With what compiler and settings does `while(true)` test true against true? I can't manage to get anything other than an unconditional jump.

Comment: while needs a condition unlike for loop in C++, in while there is no default value.

Comment: Just because `for`'s condition may have a default does not require `while` to have a default too. Why does `for`'s condition have a default, and `while` doesn't? Who knows... Who cares... Not something to lose any sleep over. Just have to remember that this is how  C++, then flip the page to the next chapter in your C++ book.

Comment: @charunnera  "I've written infinite loop  like this numerous times over the years in both C and C++, but today" I asked myself: "What was I doing?":)

Comment: Thanks guys. I'll just chalk it up to another special case. @VladfromMoscow, yes I was smiling as I wrote that...I'm sure I had this same question when I first saw the for(;;) syntax, figured out the answer and used the syntax without thinking...and then one day (today) someone asked me and I was like "good question".:)

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I only compiled for(;;); to asm and it used an unconditional jump.  While researching this question, someone else mentioned that while(true); tested each loop and I bit. I removed that statement since I didn't actually verify it. Thanks for calling that out.

Comment: Note [infinite loops are undefined behavior](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3592557/1708801) outside of the for case and if the loop contains observable behavior. C11 makes an exception for [controlling expressions that are constant expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28681034/1708801)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The C Standard explicitly describes this behavior of `for` loops:

> [C11 Draft Standard §6.8.5.3 2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.8.5.3)
>
> Both clause-1 and expression-3 can be omitted. An omitted expression-2
>   is replaced by a nonzero constant.

Similarly, for C++:

> [C++14 Draft Standard §6.5.3
>   2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/n4618.pdf#section.6.5)
>
> Either or both of the *condition* and the *expression* can be omitted.
>   A missing *condition* makes the implied **while** clause equivalent to
>   **while(true)**.

Comment: Thanks for pointing there is an explicitly defined behavior for omitting the expression.

Comment: This question has been asked many times before and has many duplicates, including highly upvoted ones. You are a member with a lot of reputation, and thus have been given privilege and understanding to do the following. Improving StackOverflow by reducing duplicates by voting to close as a duplicate instead of answering. Such action will greatly improve the community at the negligible disadvantage to yourself. Thank you.

Comment: @2501-- I agree that this question is a duplicate; in fact I knew that it was a duplicate of the question that you linked to, since that was my first question on SO! When I asked that question, I found no other questions that asked about the _nature_ of this behavior (a result of the evaluation model or defined behavior). When I answered, it seemed to me that one duplicate is not a bad thing. Of course, the answer turns out to be mundane.

Answer (score 4):

The behaviors are defined by the language (C++). For the [for loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/for), the condition part is optional:

> Syntax
>
> formal syntax:
>
> ```
> attr(optional) for ( init-statement condition(optional) ; iteration_expression(optional) ) statement
> ```

and (emphasis mine)

> The above syntax produces code equivalent to:
>
> ```
> {
>     init_statement 
>     while ( condition ) { 
>         statement 
>         iteration_expression ; 
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Except that
>
> **3) Empty condition is equivalent to `while(true)`**

For [while loop](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/while), the condition part is necessary, it can't be ommitted.

> Syntax
>
> ```
> attr(optional) while ( condition ) statement
> ```

Comment: Thank you for your response

Comment: This question has been asked many times before and has many duplicates, including highly upvoted ones. You are a senior member with a lot of reputation, and thus have been given privilege and understanding to do the following. Improving StackOverflow by reducing duplicates by voting to close as a duplicate instead of answering. Such action will greatly improve the community at the negligible disadvantage to yourself. Thank you.