# Recvfrom null buffer returning errno EFAULT?

Tags: c, sockets, null, asyncsocket, errno

I'm programming a UDP non-blocking socket and I have the function

```
void recvflush(int sockfd) {
  ssize_t num;
  while (errno != EWOULDBLOCK) {
    num = recvfrom(sockfd, NULL, maxpack, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (num < 0 && errno != EWOULDBLOCK)
      error("recvfrom() failed", strerror(errno));
  }
}
```

to flush the receive buffer. However, it is returning EFAULT (Bad address) when I call it, and I make sure I have the sockfd set when I do. Help!

Thanks

Comment: Where'd you get the idea you could pass `NULL` as the second argument to `recvfrom()`?  That's why it's crashing, because the OS can't write the received data to that "address".  You'll probably have to allocate a local buffer (`char buf[1500];`) to read into, even though you're just going to throw the data away.

Comment: Come to think of it, since excess data (from packets too big to fit in the user-supplied buffer) is discarded, I guess you could get away with`char buf[1]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there some reason you *expect* that giving a `NULL` pointer to `recvfrom` will cause it to flush messages? You've told it your buffer is `maxpack` bytes long, but then you've given it an invalid pointer, so `EFAULT` is the correct and expected `errno`.

You should be able to supply a *length* of zero to discard a queued message: According to the `recvfrom(2)` man page, if the buffer length provided is too short for a message, the remaining data bytes will be discarded; that should include discarding of *all* the bytes.

Now, once you have provided a length of zero, you could *also* supply a `NULL` pointer since there is no requirement for any portion of the buffer to be valid in that case.  But that is not because `NULL` pointer is specially recognized but because the provided length requires no part of it to point to valid memory.

Comment: Ah, okay. Great answer, that sounds perfect. I just thought I might as well keep the `maxpack` bytes as a parameter because I set it as a global anyways for the signal handler. I thought of putting 0 but I was a bit skeptical at first. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Per the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/2/recvfrom) for `recvfrom()`, `EFAULT` is reported when:

> EFAULT
>   The receive buffer pointer(s) point outside the process's address space.

Assuming your `maxpack` variable is > 0, `recvfrom()` is expecting to be able to write bytes to the buffer pointed to by the `buf` parameter, but you are passing `NULL` for that parameter, hence the error.

Why are you checking `errno` before calling `recvfrom()`? You should be calling `recvfrom()` first, and THEN check for an error.  And stop looping when *any* error *other than* `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN`, `EINTR`, or `EMSGSIZE` is reported.

Also, keep in mind that UDP supports 0-length packets, in which case `recvfrom()` would return 0 instead of -1, and `errno` would not be set.  Make sure you account for that in your loop, too.

Try this instead:

```
void recvflush(int sockfd) {
  ssize_t num;
  do {
    num = recvfrom(sockfd, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (num < 0) {
      if ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN))
        break;
      if ((errno != EINTR) && (errno != EMSGSIZE)) {
        error("recvfrom() failed", strerror(errno));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  while (true);
}
```

Or, if `recvfrom()` doesn't accept a 0-length buffer, then give it a small buffer to write into:

```
void recvflush(int sockfd) {
  ssize_t num;
  char c;
  do {
    num = recvfrom(sockfd, &c, 1, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (num < 0) {
      if ((errno == EWOULDBLOCK) || (errno == EAGAIN))
        break;
      if ((errno != EINTR) && (errno != EMSGSIZE)) {
        error("recvfrom() failed", strerror(errno));
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  while (true);
}
```

Note that if your socket is NOT non-blocking, then `EWOULDBLOCK`/`EAGAIN` will not be reported since the call will block until data is available, so you should use `select()` or `(e)poll()` to check if the socket has any queued packets before entering the `recvfrom()` loop.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops/28681034#28681034, however your case is portable never mind (I think, infinite loop are so tricky sometime)