# How to check atomic object impact in producer / consumer schema?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I want to implement the following

1. Two threads: `producer` (can change shared variable `a`), `consumer` (waiting for shared variable change)
2. I want to use atomic to synchronize threads

**Problem** - I was running my code with `int a;` and `std::atomic<int> a;`  but in 100% cases I have the same result on my PC.

```
calculate_val 
process 1
```

How can I see changes of code with and without atomics?

```
using namespace std;

atomic<int> a; // I was replacing with int a; and always have the same result
int val;

int calculate_val() {
    cout << "calculate_val " << endl;
    return 1;
}

void process(int val) {
    cout << "process " << val << endl;
} 

void threadProducer() {
    val = calculate_val();
    a = 1;
}

void threadConsumer() {
    while (!a) {
        
    }
    process(val);
}




int main() {
    thread t2(threadConsumer);
    thread t1(threadProducer);

    t2.join(); // was trying to change order
    t1.join();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you expect it to be different? You literally say that `threadConsumer()` shouldn't call `process()` while `a` is not set.

Comment: Making `a` plain `int` exhibits undefined behavior by way of a data race. "Seems to work" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior. I wonder whether you are compiling with optimizations enabled; an optimizer could remove `while (!a) {}` loop entirely, since in a conforming program `a` cannot change.

Comment: @lorro: Without atomics or locking (the I/O introduces locking you don't see, which does mess with things), the write to `a` could be seen before the write to `val`. Threading is weird.

Comment: With gcc and -O3 specified, your loop is optimized out, see: https://godbolt.org/z/94YPxPbhh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your scenario is too simple. On an architecture with strongly ordered memory semantics (e.g. x86 and descendants, which, given you refer to "my PC", is probably what you're using), with compiler optimizations turned off, as long as the compiler doesn't reorder `threadProducer`'s `a = 1;` ahead of the function call (it has no reason to), doesn't cache the value of `a` for the `while (!a)` test, and doesn't eliminate the `while(a){}` loop, the atomics won't make a difference.

Your existing code could fail without atomics:

1. On a machine with weakly ordered memory semantics (the writes to `a` and `val` could become visible in `threadConsumer` in any order, and it could take an arbitrarily long for them to become visible). I suspect the locking built-in to the `iostream` library, and the C `stdio` it wraps, would probably trigger cache flushes though, so your I/O trying to *observe* the races is in fact *changing* the behavior.
2. On any machine if the compiler chose to cache the value of `a` in `threadConsumer` for efficiency (non-`volatile`, non-`atomic` values can be cached to save overhead because it's assumed they're only accessed from one thread, and the loading thread isn't changing it).
3. On any machine if the compiler [decides to eliminates the `while (a) {}` loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2178115/364696), due the non-atomic `a` potentially creating an infinite loop if cached as suggested in #2.
4. On any machine if the compiler chose to reorder `a = 1;` ahead of `val = calculate_val();` (since neither line depends on any values computed in the other line, an optimizing compiler could choose to do them in either order). In practice, given the aforementioned locking in the I/O layers, the compiler *won't* swap these lines, but it *could* if the I/O were removed.

I'm not going to give an example of things that could go wrong, because a cursory search will find all sorts of examples of when and why you use atomics. What's important to know is that, even in your simple scenario where you *thought* it was safe without them, it wasn't. Even turning up optimizations might cause your code with a non-atomic `a` to stop behaving on x86-64 machines, and x86-64 is already threading/atomics on easy mode.

Comment: Not only the compiler is allowed to reorder it, the processor is also allowed to reorder instructions.
When the function calculate_val is complicated and may have some optimized microcode instructions with computation holes in the pipeline, it is very likely, that the assignment is done in between.

Comment: @FabianKeßler: Yep. I don't believe x86-64 will ever do this (the strongly ordered memory model means even if it does the work in the pipeline out of order, it's not observable in any reasonable way), but on another architecture, yep, reordering is a thing.