# Why does gcc -O1 optimization break this code modifying VRAM in a loop for a Gameboy Advance ROM?

Tags: c, gcc, arm, devkitpro, game-boy-advance

I'm working on a simple Gameboy Advance ROM and trying to understand why the following code works with the gcc `-O0` option, but crashes (white emulator screen) with `-O1` or above:

```
int main () {
    // Set video mode 3 and background 2
    *(unsigned int*)0x04000000 = 0x0403;

    int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 1; x++){
        // Set a single pixel at position (120, 80) in VRAM to red
        ((unsigned short*)0x06000000)[120+80*240] = 0x001F;
    };

    while(1);

    return 0;
}
```

The loop is obviously unnecessary, but I used it to create a minimal example of the crashing behavior. Without the loop, the code works properly regardless of optimization level. With the loop, it crashes on `-O1` and higher, but works on `-O0`.

The same behavior occurs whether or not I'm actually using `x` in the body of the loop (for example, using `x` to calculate a pixel position). As far as I can tell, I get the breakage on higher optimization levels any time I try to do this type of direct memory modification in a loop.

What's going on here? What optimization is breaking the code? And does it point to some issue in the way I'm doing things? Thanks for any help!

A few more details:

- I'm using devkitpro/devkitarm
- I'm using NanoBoyAdvance as the emulator
- I'm running on Ubuntu
- Full command:

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -MMD -MP -MF /path/to/myfile.d  -g -Wall -O1 -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mtune=arm7tdmi -mthumb -mthumb-interwork -iquote /path/to/include -I/opt/devkitpro/libgba/include -I/path/to/build -c /path/to/source/myfile.c -o myfile.o
```

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly code to see what really happens? How is it different from an unoptimized (and supposedly working) build?

Comment: By the way, how sure are you about using `120+80*240` as array index? Shouldn't the index depend on `x` somehow? Or perhaps two nested loops, one for `x` and one for `y`?

Comment: I'm confident on the array index. It works when outside of the loop. I was going to set many pixels in a loop (iterating over `x` and actually using it) and that also doesn't work with `-O1` and above. I narrowed it down to this minimal example that doesn't use x at all to show that it's not an issue with `x`'s variable size or anything like that. This is what I was actually trying to do (draw a horizontal line) when I ran into this error:
```
int x;
    for(x = 0; x < 100; x++){
        videoMemory[x+80*240] = 0x001F;
    };
```
(works on -O0, breaks on -O1 and above)

Comment: I'll attempt to look at the assembly, but it's not something I have any experience in

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mre] of the *non-working* code. Seeing working code doesn't tell us anything.

Comment: The example in the original question is non-working on `O1`. It works on `O0`. I'm trying to figure out why `O1` breaks it

Comment: Try changing `while(1);` to something that can actually end.

Comment: Thanks @RetiredNinja that fixed it! Curious if you have any insight as to why? Also, I'm not sure if you know what is best practice here. I used the infinite loop on the suggestion of the Tonc tutorial I'm following. It said not to let the main return as it's undefined behavior on the gameboy. I suppose with a more robust ROM it won't matter because I'll be doing something in that loop and GCC will be ok with it, but still curious.

Tutorial link I'm looking at: https://www.coranac.com/tonc/text/first.htm

Comment: I believe a loop that can be proven to never end can cause undefined behavior. [Are compilers allowed to eliminate infinite loops?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2178115/are-compilers-allowed-to-eliminate-infinite-loops)

Comment: @RetiredNinja: But there's a special exception for trivial infinite loops like `while (1);`, where the controlling expression is a constant.  So the code here should not be UB.

Comment: @NateEldredge I'm admittedly not the best standard reader but I thought `for (;;)` was okay and `while(1)` was not. The only reason I thought of it was that there was another question yesterday where a `while (1)` loop caused unpredictable results. It was c++ though and I don't know if those rules are different. *shrug* Figured it was worth a shot in the dark.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: Indeed, C++ is different - in C++ every loop must terminate or at least cause externally visible side effects, so `for(;;);` and `while(1);` are both illegal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Writes to memory-mapped hardware generally need to be done through pointers to `volatile` types, e.g. `*(volatile unsigned int*)0x04000000 = 0x0403;`.  Otherwise the compiler is free to assume they have no side effects and can be optimized in unexpected ways.  Here, this applies both to the store which sets the video mode, and the one which puts the pixel.

(Actually, when writing to video memory, you may be okay with allowing some optimization; e.g. you don't care if all the writes happen in exactly the specified order, so long as they all happen eventually.  In that case you can often get away with non-`volatile` stores together with some sort of compiler-specific memory barrier that acts as though it may observe them, e.g. `asm("" : : : "memory");` in gcc).

What's happened in this case is that the compiler optimized out the first store, which sets the video mode: https://godbolt.org/z/4dn9dhh6j

```
main:
        ldr     r3, .L3
        mov     r2, #31
        strh    r2, [r3, #240]  @ movhi
.L2:
        b       .L2
.L3:
        .word   100701696
```

I'm not an expert on the details of gcc's optimizer, but my assumption is that the compiler sees that there are no reads from memory anywhere between the store and the infinite loop.  Therefore, it assumes that no code in the program can read back the value you wrote to address `0x04000000`, since nothing that follows the infinite loop (including code outside of `main`) can ever execute.  If the value can never be read, and the write itself does not have a side effect (assumed because it's not `volatile`), then it's a *dead store* and there was no need to write it in the first place.

However, by that logic one would think it would *also* have optimized out the store that puts the pixel, but it did not.  So maybe there is something else going on that I am missing.

Comment: Interestingly, clang doesn't optimize out the first store, but it reorders it with the second one, which is probably also bad: https://godbolt.org/z/vE9x87Wxa